# How to check Google sign-in validation in iOS after remove access from user Security account

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

How to validate or check the google sign in user, if the user is removed access from their account management or still valid? image shown below. i have tried out
`if(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser != nil)`
and
`guard let googleSignIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance() else { return } if (googleSignIn.hasPreviousSignIn()) { googleSignIn.restorePreviousSignIn() }`.
but it doesn't work out. How to validate the user if removed access or not.
Can anyone help on this?
[image]

Comment: When you try and use the token to access their account details it will fail

Comment: @Paulw11, I can still able to use id_token

Answer (score 0):

Do like this, you will get the call back in the delegate method. If it fails with an error, you have to ask the user to re-login.

```
guard let googleSignIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance() else { return }
    if (googleSignIn.hasPreviousSignIn()) {
      googleSignIn.restorePreviousSignIn()
    }
```

Comment: Tried this as well it provides me the valid id_token again

Comment: Are you using any other google API after sign-in?